# Rendering button event on parts of the screen?

Tags: blackberry

Hi I am new to Blackberry.I have a Bitmap which is used as a homescreen and it contains four stages.I want to make these stages as Buttons.I am developing the application in storm version.How can I implement  these parts of the screen as Button events?Any answers appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the BitmapButton example

Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers
Started 04-21-2010
Modified 05-10-2010
[link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)

Comment: Thanks Endevour for suggestion.But I want to create buttons on these four stages but these buttons should be transparent. I mean I want to make these buttons invisible. How can I do it?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. ButtonFields do have ButtonField().setVisualState(state) method to distinguish their state. If you need to set a button invisible at all, you have to remove it from its Manager at all.

Comment: What I want to do is, make some part of the  of the screen as Button render service.I have a Bitmap which is used as homescreen of the application.From that screen when I click on some part of it , it should take to the new screen.I thought you understand well what my issue is. Thanks in advance Endevour.

Comment: maybe one approach would be to split the image in parts and layout them like a grid, so you can get a single event per (bitmap)field. In your screens navigationUnlick method you can check which field is selected and handle the click.

Comment: Hi Endevour thankful to ur suggestion,but how can i split the image and make them in a grid layout.

Comment: actually I thought of splitting them manually. e.g. you split the image into 4 smaler ones... use a 2x2 grid and put every image in a 'gridcell'